# Angular Firebase 2 - Read data from the database ONCE

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I want to have a function which returns an array of strings from my firebase realtime database. However I am confused as there are no synchronous methods on `database.list('example')`. I do not want to use up a database connection as it is not needed for the values I am retrieving. Is there a way to get all the values from the list in sync, close the connection to the database and then return them?

Comment: What you want to do basically goes against every reason why you'd want to use Firebase's real-time database...

Comment: well.. euh.. make a HTTP firebase cloud function wich return the element you want. So there will be no needs to login nor keep a connection to the database

Comment: @Brandon Understandable, cloud-firestore would be more suitable for this project. However I already have established database hooked up and running in the rtdb. The functionality exists in the JavaScript SDK so there is no reason it should not exist in angular fire 2?

Comment: @ChristopheGudlake seems a bit overkill for such a simple operation as well as now digging into cloud function quotas